# Assigning a value to an object parameter without creating parent first

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

How do I assign a value to a specific parameter in a nested object where its parent is non-existent yet?

```
var obj = {
  'obj1' : {
    'obj1a' : 'obj1a'
  },
  'obj2' : 'obj2'
}

obj.obj3.obj3a = 'obj3a'  // this is what I want to work
```

But it gives out an error:

```
TypeError: obj.obj3 is undefined
```

Is it not possible for javascript to recursively create parents of children parameters?

If this is not doable at all, is there any built-in mechanism to handle such cases just so it would not generate such error? Similar to how the `?.`  functionality works. 
Eg: `console.log(obj?.obj1?.obj1a)`

Comment: You can't. You have to create the object first.

Comment: JavaScript won't create intermediate objects automatically.

Comment: You could just do `obj.obj3 = {obj3a: 'obj3a'};` If you're worried about overriding `obj3` in case it already exists, you could do `obj.obj3 = {...obj.obj3, obj3a: 'obj3a'}`

Answer (score 0):

Like `@Barmar` said in his first comment. You can do this, thought:

```js
const obj = {
  obj1:{
    obj1a:'obj1a'
  },
  obj2:'obj2'
}
obj.obj3 = {obj3a:'obj3a'};
console.log(obj);
console.log('--------------------------------------');
console.log(obj.obj3);
```